# Loop until string is found

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I need some help with my code below. What I'm trying to do is check every line going up from current cell until a text string ("Settlement Date:) is found. Then I want to grab the contents of the cell.

```
sub test

   mystring = ""
   y = -1

   Do Until mystring = ("SETTLEMENT DATE:")

       mystring = ActiveCell.Value

   Loop

End sub
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code?

Comment: What I'm having issues on is going up a cell every time condition is not met.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=-1, columnOffset:=0)`

Comment: would that work if I use .value because I don't what to move from the current cell?

Comment: "Then I want to grab the contents of the cell." Which cell are you talking about? if it's the one you found, we already know the content, it is "SETTLEMENT DATE:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Eric()
    Dim i As Long, t As String
    For i = ActiveCell.Row To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column), "SETTLEMENT DATE:") > 0 Then
            MsgBox Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]